# AFnetworking waitUntilFinish not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I am making a project that uses the AFNetworking Library. I use it to check for a login and password with the webservice. This gives me a 200-code back if it is ok. If it is 200, I set a boolean to true so that the application can continue. But this boolean is not set at the right time. I always need to press two times on my `login button` before it works. Here is my code to set the boolean.

```
    - (BOOL)credentialsValidated {
    self.progressHUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    self.progressHUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    self.progressHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    self.progressHUD.dimBackground = YES;
     [[API sharedInstance] loginCommand:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_txtLogin.text,@"email",_txtPass.text,@"pwd", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){
     //completion
         if(![json objectForKey:@"error"]){
             NSLog(@"status %@",[json valueForKeyPath:@"data.status"]);
             if([[json valueForKeyPath:@"data.status"]intValue] == 200){
                //Create user object


                _loginstatus =  YES;
                [self.progressHUD hide:YES afterDelay:5];
             }else{
                 //show validation
                 _txtLogin.text = @"";
                 _txtPass.text = @"";
                 _loginstatus = NO;
             }
         }else {
             NSLog(@"Cannot connect to the server");
         }
     }];
     if(_loginstatus){
         NSLog(@"true");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"false");
    }
    [self.progressHUD hide:YES afterDelay:5];
     return _loginstatus;
}
```

And here is my API code.

```
-(void)loginCommand:(NSMutableDictionary *)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock{
    NSLog(@"%@%@",kAPIHost,kAPILogin);
    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:kAPILogin parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData){
        //TODO: attach file if needed

    }];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        //success !
        NSLog(@"SUCCESSSS!");
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        //Failure
        NSLog(@"FAILUREE!");
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];
    [operation start];

}
```

When I put below `[operation start]` the `[operation waitUntilFinish]` code, the app crashes.

Can somebody help me with this?

Kind regards

**LOG**
Here is a print of my log **after I 2 two times** pressed the login button

```
2012-12-28 09:36:00.547 Offitel[6532:907] http://virtuele-receptie.******.sanmax.be/nl/webservice/company-user/****/*****/**************
2012-12-28 09:36:00.561 Offitel[6532:907] false
2012-12-28 09:36:01.604 Offitel[6532:907] SUCCESSSS!
2012-12-28 09:36:01.605 Offitel[6532:907] status 200
2012-12-28 09:36:20.742 Offitel[6532:907] aanmelden pressed
2012-12-28 09:36:20.746 Offitel[6532:907] http://virtuele-receptie.******.sanmax.be/nl/webservice/company-user/****/*****/**************
2012-12-28 09:36:20.748 Offitel[6532:907] true
2012-12-28 09:36:22.184 Offitel[6532:907] SUCCESSSS!
2012-12-28 09:36:22.184 Offitel[6532:907] status 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this

```
return _loginstatus;
```

You are not waiting the operation to finish, so you're not returning what your server is sending to your application. What I usually do in this cases is display an `UIActivityIndicator` when the login action is fired, and do **nothing** till' the server has responded. Then, I set the proper values to any variables and in this case I would segue to home screen.

Remember that when you're using `AFNetworking` you are always doing async stuff.

**EDIT**

Code example:

```
- (void)loginActionWithPassword:(NSString *)pass
{
    // Add progress HUD to show feedback
    // I'm using MBProgressHUD library: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD#readme
    self.progressHUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    self.progressHUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    self.progressHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    self.progressHUD.dimBackground = YES;

    // Launch the action to the server
    [Actions loginWithEmail:[self.textEmail.text lowercaseString] andPassword:pass success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        if ([Actions requestFailed:JSON]) {
            LOG(@"ERROR %@ / %@ / %@ \n", pass, request, response, JSON);
            if ([JSON[@"MSG"] isEqualToString:@"USER_NOT_REGISTERED"]) {
                self.progressHUD.labelText = @"User doesn't exist";
                self.textEmail.text = @"";
                self.textPassword.text = @"";
            } else if ([JSON[@"MSG"] isEqualToString:@"PASSWORD_INCORRECT"]) {
                self.progressHUD.labelText = @"Wrong password";
                self.textPassword.text = @"";
            }
            [self.progressHUD hide:YES afterDelay:[Utils hudDuration]];
            return;
        }
        // If everything went OK, go to this function to save user data
        // and perform segue to home screen (or dismiss modal login view)
        [self onLoginSuccessWithPassword:pass JSON:JSON response:response];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        // If something fails, display an error message
        LOG(@"ERROR:(%@): %@ / %@ / %@ / %@ \n", pass, request, response, error, JSON);
        self.progressHUD.labelText = @"Something went wrong, try again";
        [self.progressHUD hide:YES afterDelay:[Utils hudDuration]];
        return;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Oké thank you, but can you explain where [Utils hudDuration comes from?

Comment: Yes, it's just a plist entry that returns a duration in seconds.

Comment: I've edited my code with the HUD implementation. But still I need to press two times the Login-button before it works.

Comment: I also added the log in the console.

Comment: Stef, it seems to me that you're missing the async approach of `AFNetworking`. Try to put a breakpoint inside the success callback of your login function and then press the login button. If the execution does not stop in the breakpoint, you have another problem somewhere else.

Comment: @StefGeelen you are still returning the variable at the end of your function, and that's not going to work. Have you read my code? `AFNetworking` is an async library, you must do your stuff (saving info, performing segues) inside your success callback.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21807/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-amb)